# My system generated transactional Emails are going to outlook mail server though gmail is configured with the domain

Tags: email, outlook, gmail, postfix-mta, google-workspace

1. I had outlook mail server configured with my server and all system generated emails(transactional) were getting received in my Outlook inbox which was installed on my server.
2. I wanted to move into Gmail. So, I mapped my domain with gmail (G suite) changed my SMTP credentials, outbound email password, etc in postfix, then MX records were also changed.
3. Outbound emails from my system/server are going to other addresses perfectly. but copies of them are not coming to my Gmail inbox, rather they are going to the outbox inbox.

I didn't stop/uninstalled Outlook as I noticed this problem. Normal emails which are coming from separate platforms are landing in my gmail, but most of my system generated transactional email copies are going to my outlook inbox.

I am using centos, Postfix and I want my system generated emails to land in my Gmail which now mapped with my domain.

**I also contacted Google support, they told it is problem with my email configuration/routing in server.

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem just by gaining courage and deleting the outlook account. Now all emails are receiving in the Gmail smoothly.